# Make an element adjacent to the border of a floated element

Tags: html, css, css-float, pseudo-element

I want to make a white pointer stick out of the right-floated paragraph.
Here's what I achieved so far. It's far from pefect as the pointer doesn't want to stick to the border when I resize the screen.
What is the solution?

```css
#batu {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c836431/v836431507/5a2cd/Zc9FsOzRLdY.jpg) no-repeat;
    max-width: 1170px;
    background-size: cover; /* Never used this before */
}
#batu::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  overflow: nidden;
}

#batu .overlay-content {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    min-height: 517px; /* the height of the background image*/
}

.pointer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    left: 48%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/08/96ad387742f9e8fce21c53f42fe45984.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="batu">
    <div class="pointer"></div>
    <div class="overlay-content">
        <h4>Batu</h4>
        <p>blablablablablablablablablablablabla
        blablablablablablablablablablablablablb
        blablablablablablablablablablablablabla
        blablablablablablablablablablablablablb
        </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd easier if you can make your *pointer* a `after` psuedo element inside the `overlay-content`:

1. Add `position: relative` to `overlay-content`
2. The psuedo `after` element can be as follows:

   ```
   #batu .overlay-content::after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0;
     transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
     width: 10px;
     height: 24px;
     background: url(https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/08/96ad387742f9e8fce21c53f42fe45984.png) no-repeat;
   }
   ```

See demo below:

```css
#batu {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c836431/v836431507/5a2cd/Zc9FsOzRLdY.jpg) no-repeat;
  max-width: 1170px;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Never used this before */
}

#batu::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#batu .overlay-content {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  min-height: 517px;
  /* the height of the background image*/
  position: relative;
}


/*
.pointer {
    position: relative;
    top: 48%;
    left: 48%;
    float: right;
    width: 10px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/08/96ad387742f9e8fce21c53f42fe45984.png) no-repeat;
}
*/

#batu .overlay-content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url(https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/08/96ad387742f9e8fce21c53f42fe45984.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="batu">
  <!--<div class="pointer"></div>-->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <h4>Batu</h4>
    <p>blablablablablablablablablablablabla blablablablablablablablablablablablablb blablablablablablablablablablablablabla blablablablablablablablablablablablablb
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/osxo2vzL/. 
You need to put `word-wrap: break-word;` in your paragraph tag.